# Parsing items in a YAML variable in groovy jenkins pipeline

Tags: variables, jenkins, yaml, pipeline

I encountered such a problem that it is impossible to loop through the structure of the yaml variable.

Let me explain.

There is a pipeline jenkis groovy, where the variable YAML is loaded.

It looks like this:

```
var1:
  item1:
    - { name: "1-1", type: "jks" }
    - { name: "1-2", type: "p12" }
  item2:
    - { name: "2-1", type: "pem" }
    - { name: "2-2", type: "jks" }
  item3:
    - { name: "3-1", type: "jks" }
```

I'm trying to work with it somehow through loops, but it's not working.

First I am loading this variable from a file:

```
configData = readYaml file: "var.yaml"
def var1 = configData['var1']
```

Then I want to go through all item1-item3 and do some operations on their names.

For example this is what I tried to do:

```
for (item in var1) {
  println(item)
}
```

But unfortunately, item in the for loop is some entity (apparently map) from which item1 cannot be selected, but only the whole subset:

```
item1:[[name:1-1, type:jks], [name:1-2, type:p12]]
```

Does anyone know how I can extract only the naming of item1?

Comment: `var1` is a map, so try `var1.each { key, value -> println("${key}:${value}") }`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't do anything

Comment: Try to print `configData` and see what you get

Comment: That's right, I unfortunately messed up the variables. After substituting the correct variable, everything worked, including the for loop